# SQL Server: Update duplicates with data from first duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I get the following result:

```
**SID**  **KL**   **ABT**  **KLH**  **ABTH**
013239   PKB4     GT      NULL      NULL
013239   TM4A     KD      NULL      NULL
013243   KSB4     GT      NULL      NULL
013243   TM4A     KD      NULL      NULL
```

with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SID, KL, ABT, KLH, ABTH 
FROM 
    [SGB] 
WHERE 
    SID IN (SELECT SID FROM [SGB] GROUP BY SID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I'd like to update **KLH** and **ABTH** with the content of **KL** and **ABT** from the first duplicate.

should look like this:

```
**SID**  **KL**   **ABT**  **KLH**  **ABTH**
013239   PKB4     GT      PKB4      GT
013239   TM4A     KD      PKB4      GT
013243   KSB4     GT      KSB4      GT
013243   TM4A     KD      KSB4      GT
```

Many thanks!

Comment: **Show us YOUR effort!** What do you have? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do you know which record of the duplicates is the one to use to update the two columns for all of those duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is query which update all duplicated `SID` with first value:

```
;WITH tempSGB AS (
    SELECT SID
    , KL
    , ABT
    , KLH
    , ABTH
    --Next column set numbers in order for rows
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SID ORDER BY KL) AS ROWNUM
    FROM SGB
    WHERE SID IN (SELECT SID FROM SGB GROUP BY SID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
)

UPDATE s SET
s.KLH = tmp.KL
, s.ABTH = tmp.ABT
FROM tempSGB tmp
INNER JOIN SGB s ON s.SID = tmp.SID
WHERE ROWNUM = 1; --here we choose only first row from duplicated
```

[About ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

But you did not mention how query can decide which row is first from all duplicated(in the example i set in order by `KL`)

Here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6094/24) is a sample query with data for testing

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * into #temptable from  [SGB] 
  update #temptable t
  set **KLH** =**KL**
  set **ABTH**=**ABT** 
  from [SGB] s  
  inner join s.**SID**=t.**SID**
```

Comment: Are you sure with this answer ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do in this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B
SET KLH=A.KL,
ABTH=A.ABT
FROM [SGB] A JOIN [SGB]  B ON A.SID=B.SID
```